# Python StanfordNerTagger coreNLP output different than the online demo of stanford ner tagger

Tags: python, nltk, named-entity-recognition, stanford-nlp

I am using stanford coreNLP [stanford-ner-2015-12-09] with python nltk StanfordNERTAgger but it has different results than that of the online demo.

I went through this thread "https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2011-August/001283.html" which says that "they use the same models, but CoreNLP first POS tags the data, thenparses it. This leads to different results."

Is there a way to align the results as per the online demo as I found it better than coreNLP for most of the examples I tried.

```
CoreNLP
[(u'Tom', u'PERSON'), (u'Cruise', u'PERSON'), (u'was', u'O'), (u'born', u'O'), (u'on', u'O'), (u'July', u'O'), (u'3,', u'O'), (u'1962,', u'O'), (u'in', u'O'), (u'Syracuse,', u'O'), (u'New', u'LOCATION'), (u'York', u'LOCATION')]

OnlineDEMO
Tom Cruise was born on July 3, 1962, in Syracuse, New York.
Person                                  Location  Location
```

Comment: Is this about differences in representation or about the fact that CoreNLP didn't tag "Syracuse" as a location?

Comment: @lenz  CoreNLP didn't tag "Syracuse" as a location!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the tokenization:

```
st = StanfordNERTagger(model_path, stanford_tagger_jar, encoding='utf8')
r=st.tag("Tom Cruise was born on July 3, 1962, in Syracuse, New York.".split())
for e in r:
    print e
```

This does not tag Syracuse as location:

```
(u'Tom', u'PERSON')
(u'Cruise', u'PERSON')
(u'was', u'O')
(u'born', u'O')
(u'on', u'O')
(u'July', u'O')
(u'3,', u'O')
(u'1962,', u'O')
(u'in', u'O')
(u'Syracuse,', u'O')
(u'New', u'LOCATION')
(u'York.', u'LOCATION')
```

But this will do:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
st = StanfordNERTagger(model_path, stanford_tagger_jar, encoding='utf8')
r=st.tag(word_tokenize("Tom Cruise was born on July 3, 1962, in Syracuse, New York."))
for e in r:
    print e
```

```
(u'Tom', u'PERSON')
(u'Cruise', u'PERSON')
(u'was', u'O')
(u'born', u'O')
(u'on', u'O')
(u'July', u'O')
(u'3', u'O')
(u',', u'O')
(u'1962', u'O')
(u',', u'O')
(u'in', u'O')
(u'Syracuse', u'LOCATION')
(u',', u'O')
(u'New', u'LOCATION')
(u'York', u'LOCATION')
(u'.', u'O')
```